# Is there any way to tell the difference between EOL and EOF in canonical mode?

Tags: c, unix, io, terminal

If you are reading lines from a terminal in canonical mode, is there any way to tell the difference between a line terminated with EOL (Enter) and EOF (Ctrl-D)? My understanding is that both will return the number of bytes read from read().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EOL on an empty line, the byte count will be 1, for the newline.

For EOF on an empty line, the byte count will be 0, for 'there was no more data'.

Comment: What if the line has text in it?

Comment: I wondered if you were going to pick up on that!  If there is text on the line, the data is sent for reading, without a newline at the end, and you get a value of 1 or more returned.  If you type EOF a second time (meaning, you hit control-D again, typically), then the second time you get 0 returned, indicating EOF.  Try playing with `cat`; type a partial line, hit control-D; type some more; hit control-D, then control-D again (all with no newlines).

Comment: I still dont get it. If type text "abc" and press enter, read() will return 3 and "abc". If I type "abc" and press Ctrl-D doesn't the same thing happen? If so, how do you tell the difference?

Comment: If you type "abc" and enter, `read()` will return 4, `"abc\n"`.  Newline is a character; it gets read and counted.  Come to that, even the null byte is a character and gets read and counted (^@ or control-@), though it messes up strings if there are characters after it. If you type "abc" and control-D (EOF), then you get 3 characters.

Comment: You can try a trivial program: `#include <unistd.h>`  and `#include <stdio.h>` and `int main(void) { char buffer[2048]; int n; while ((n = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) printf("%d: <<%.*s>>\n", n, n, buffer); return 0; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the last character read (unless no characters were read, in which case you have an EOF).

```
int nr = read(0, buffer, sizeof buffer);
if (nr > 0) {
  if (buffer[nr - 1] == '\n')
    { /* EOL typed */ }
  else if (nr == sizeof buffer)
    { /* Filled the buffer */ }
  else
    { /* Probably an EOF was typed, not at the start of a line */ }
else if (nr < 0)
  { /* handle error */ }
else
  { /* EOF */ }
```

Comment: If you key enough characters to fill up the buffer, you'll that many characters in the read without the final `\n`, so you have to double check (for **read(2)** returning 0) for a real `EOF`.